# Capybara instance of "browser" for Page Object Model?

Tags: ruby, capybara, pageobjects

Im writing a framework using Capybara and the Page Object Model for a web application. It's my first time writing my own framework and using PoM for automation.

My base "Page Object" essentially initializes the driver and is used in every other page object child class (for the individual pages)

```
class PageObject
    include Capybara::DSL
    BASE_URL = 'https://www.atesturl.com'
    Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5

    def initialize

        Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
            Capybara::Selenium::Driver.load_selenium
            browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |opts|
              # Workaround https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2650&q=load&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary
              opts.args << '--disable-site-isolation-trials'
            end
            Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
          end

        Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome_headless do |app|
            Capybara::Selenium::Driver.load_selenium
            browser_options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new.tap do |opts|
              opts.args << '--headless'
              opts.args << 'window-size=2880,1800'
              opts.args << '--disable-gpu' if Gem.win_platform?
              #opts.args << '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
              # Workaround https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2650&q=load&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary
              opts.args << '--disable-site-isolation-trials'
            end
            Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: browser_options)
          end

        Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
    end

    def visit_url
        visit BASE_URL
    end

  end
```

In most examples of PoM I see the methods returning an instance of that page object, but generally they use some `@browser` instance variable that is passed around. Within my test scripts I simple call an instance of the Base page object class via `let(:p) {PageObject.new}` and then `p.visit_url` then make new instances of the other page objects via `new`....but this seems like the wrong way to do it.

How exactly do I return a instance of the `@browser` or driver that I can pass around? And how should I be calling it in my spec?

Comment: Trying to understand your question ... so currently the 'browser' is some invisible global (that's why you call `visit` without a caller) but you want to instead have it be a variable you can pass around?

Comment: Basically, as thats how I see people do method chaining returning page objects. I'd assume maybe i'd call an instance of `@browser` possibly in the constructor perhaps?

Comment: Well, you can return `self` from methods such as `visit_url` which would make it chainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to be registering your drivers in the initialize for the base PageObject since that means every object created will be registering new driver configs - which isn't desirable.

When you include Capybara::DSL into your class you're including methods that end up calling methods on `Capybara.current_session`. ie `visit` => `Capybara.current_session.visit`.  The result of `Capybara.current_session` is the "@browser" instance you're asking about since it encapsulates the driver/browser instance. The issue with the way you've currently implemented that is that if any code changes the current session then all your objects will suddenly refer to the new session. If instead you store a reference to the session you want the object to use in each object and call the Capybara methods on that session rather than using Capybara::DSL (`@session.visit ...`) then you can be sure the session an object is using doesn't change unexpectedly.

Also note that things like `Capybara.default_max_wait_time`, `Capybara.current_driver', etc are global settings so setting them inside your PageObject class isn't a great idea.

Comment: Where would be the appropriate places to store those global settings (This isn't a rails repository fwiw). And you say "If instead you store a reference to the session you want the object to use in each object". Im a bit confused at what you mean or an example of this and what specifically I did that causes this issue?
 And im not sure what code would be changing the current session? (I've been using this example with no problems so far, but it didn't 'feel' right.

Comment: @msmith1114 The current session can be changed anywhere by using `using_session`, changing the current driver, calling `session_name=` or setting `Capybara.app` - Generally you wouldn't want that changing the session used by existing page objects.  As for the global settings - generally they would be set one time wherever you're doing the initial setup for your app.

Comment: @msmith1114 For the instance of the session - if in your initialize method you set `@session = Capybara.current_session` and then called all capybara methods on @session (@session.visit, @session.find, etc) you would no longer have the issue of the session potentially being changed.  Each object would store the current session at the time the object was created.  The better option is to pass in the session when creating the objects - where you could initially pass in `Capybara.current_session` when creating the main Page - and then it could pass that on when creating the child objects

Comment: So maybe just in each page object I can have an initialize method that takes a variable and stores that in an `@browser` or `@session` variable (used in that page object). I guess in the test script (using rspec) I can just create this @session variable to pass within the `let` before each describe scenario.

In this case I need to remove the Capybara::DSL call i'd assume in the beginning? Just trying to think of where exactly the best place to register my driver is. Since this isn't a rails setup (but just a ruby one)